# Python HTTP Request to replace bash curl

Tags: python, bash, curl

I'm porting some automation scripts from bash to python, and they're almost ll curl commands of the following format:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{               "Request": {
                          "MessageID": "xxxx",
                          "MessageDateTime": "xxxxx",
                          "SourceSystem": "xxxx",

           }
}' https://myUrl.xxx
```

What's the best way to structure this in Python accurately? So far I have:

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'All the data'}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("myUrl.xxx")
conn.request("POST", "", payload, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response
```

I want to make sure the -k, -d, and -x bash options are being reflected in this script. Thank you!

Comment: You import requests but don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `requests.post` directly. `-k` corresponds to `verify=False`:

```
from datetime import datetime as DateTime
import requests
import json

URL = "https://myUrl.xxx"

message = {
    "Request": {
        "MessageID": "xxxx",
        "MessageDateTime": DateTime.now().isoformat(),
        "SourceSystem": "xxxx",
    }
}

response = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(message), verify=False, headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})
data = response.json()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm new to Python, so in the message key pair structure, how can I insert a variable containing the current ISO data timestamp after "MessageDateTime"? Thank you!

Comment: @EschersEnigma `import datetime; now = datetime.datetime.now() ... "MessageDateTime": now`

Comment: You can also say `json=message`, which does the `json.dumps` and the headers for you.