# How can I post http request instead of using cURL?

Tags: python, curl

I am using [anki-connect](https://github.com/FooSoft/anki-connect) to communicate with [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/), a spaced repetition software.
In readme.md, it uses following command to get deck name.

```
curl localhost:8765 -X POST -d "{\"action\": \"deckNames\", \"version\": 5}"
```

It works right in my Windows system.
How can I use python instead of cURL?
 I've tried this but get no luck.

```
import requests  
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8765", data={'action': 'guiAddCards', 'version': 5})
print(r.text)
```

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? Presumably you're getting some sort of error. What is the server returning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: Can you be more detailed about what exact error or issue you are facing? You should be able to find plenty of examples of python making a post request.

Comment: It would help if you posted the error. However one thing you may have trouble with is that by default `data` in `requests.post()` defaults to form encoded parameters. You need to specify if you're sending JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python HTTP Request to replace bash curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731368/python-http-request-to-replace-bash-curl)

Answer (score 1):

When creating request you should:

- provide `Content-Type` header
- provide data in format that matches `Content-Type` header
- make sure application supports the format

Both `curl` and `python` examples you gave sends request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the default one. The difference is `curl` passes string and `python` passes an array.

Let's compare `curl` and `requests` and what is really posted:

**Curl**

```
$ curl localhost -X POST -d "{\"action\": \"deckNames\", \"version\": 5}"
```

Headers:

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Posted data:

```
[
    '{"action": "deckNames", "version": 5}'
]
```

**Python**

```
import requests  
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1", data={'action': 'guiAddCards', 'version': 5})
print(r.text)
```

Headers:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.10.0
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Posted data:

```
[
    'action' -> 'guiAddCards',
    'version' -> '5',
]
```

---

As you can see, incorrect post data format breaks your app.

To be sure, that posted JSON data will be properly read by application you should make requests like that:

**Curl**

```
$ curl localhost:8765 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"action": "deckNames", "version": 5}'
```

**Python**

```
import requests  
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8765", json={'action': 'guiAddCards', 'version': 5})
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried following after digging and this works.
Can anybody share the reason. Thanks.

```
import requests
import json

#r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8765", data={'action': 'guiAddCards', 'version': 5})
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8765', data=json.dumps({'action': 'guiAddCards', 'version': 5}))
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is a reply to user2444791's answer. I can't reply with a comment because I don't have the reputation to comment (I'm new, please forgive a breech of etiquette!)*

Without the exact error message, it's hard to be sure, but...

Looking at the [Anki Connect API](https://foosoft.net/projects/anki-connect/#sample-invocation), it expects its POST-ed data to be a single string which contains a JSON object, not a key/value dictionary equivalent to that JSON object.

> Every request consists of a JSON-encoded object containing an action, a version, and a set of contextual params.

Their example code (in Javascript): `xhr.send(JSON.stringify({action, version, params}));`

It might be as simple as sending your data in the wrong format. In the first example, you are sending a dictionary with the key/vale pairs already parsed. In the second example, you're sending a string for them to parse instead.